# Different links to ultimately the same page on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm wondering if some of you could help me out a bit here as I'm a bit consfused.

the way it's setup is that you can get to the same page via 3 or 4 different routes as below:

https://tesorotiles.co.uk/type/wall-tiles/rho

https://tesorotiles.co.uk/by-area/bathroom-tiles/rho

and there another 2-3 pages which lead to the RHO range

These 3 are the exact same page and we've done it this way to make sure there is no break in the breadcrumb. Is this ok SEO wise or anyone have any recommendation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Afaik it is ok, as long as you activate the "canonical url" for products. Then every search engine knows, that this is only a representation of the "offical" url which is the product url without any category

Comment: Yes good point, forgot about canonicals.

Comment: Ha. You beat me to it.

Comment: Yup...............

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an SEO expert but as I understand it you should not include category paths in URL's.  If you do then as far as Google is concerned you have duplicate content which you can be penalised for.  If you are concerned about the breadcrumbs then you don't need to be, they will still reflect the category path you took to reach that product page.